# What are some recursive properties of Merten function or Summatory Liouville function?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Both Merten function and Summatory Liouville function show some kinds of "scale invariance" properties. (Those functions also display some kind of 
"periodic" behavior.(

Just wonder if those "scale invariance" properties are related to some kind of recursive properties of those functions.

What are some recursive properties of Merten function and Summatory Liouville function ? Were there any previous results on those ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "scale invariance"?

Comment: assuming the RH : $M(x) = \mathcal{O}(1)  + \sqrt{x} \sum_t  \frac{x^{it}}{(1/2+it)\zeta'(1/2+it)}$ (where $1/2+it$ are the non-trivial zeros) so $\displaystyle\frac{M(e^u)}{e^{u/2}}$ is an almost periodic function plus a $\mathcal{O}(e^{-u/2})$ term

Answer (score 0):

You can find some results about the recursive properties of Merten's function here:
http://www.unirioja.es/cu/jvarona/downloads/Benito-Varona-TOMATJ-Mertens.pdf

Especially there is a simple result:

$$M(n)=1-\sum_{2 \le i \le n}M(\frac{n}{i})$$